# Statement about subspaces. True or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**If H is a subspace of $R^n$, then there is a n×n matrix A such that H = Col A.**

Is this true or false, and why? To be honest I have been looking at this statement for days, but I don't understand it or find anything in my that book explains me something about this.

Comment: Hint: take a basis for $H$.

Comment: @babu_babu The thing that confuses me is how can one take a basis for the subspace $H$ in $R^n$ when I don't know what $n$ is, and what vectors and how many vectors that span $H$ ?

Comment: @Mathmomat55 It's a general fact that any finite-dimensional vector space has a basis. The best place to learn the basics of this theory is from Axler's book "Linear algebra done right" which I am sure you can find a PDF of online.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I will try to find that book!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose a basis of $H$, use those vectors as columns and add a bunch of zero-columns to get a $n\times n$-matrix.

Comment: I'm not very good at this part in linear algebra. I know it might be stupid to ask, but how do I choose a basis of H?

Comment: Starting with a non-zero vector $v_1$ in $H$, successively pick $v_{k+1}\in H\setminus\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ until the span is all of $H$.

Comment: I'm sorry, it all sounds a bit complicated to me. I must lack some of the important knowledge to understand this unfortunately. Do you know about some links or anything that can help me understand the problem? Because I don't want to bother you with to many questions

Comment: Is the statement true or false by the way? The most important thing to me is to find an explanation, and then I need to know if my explanation leads to the right answer

Comment: Any course or textbook on linear algebra will do the job really. And yes it is true, I gave you a recipe for constructing a matrix $A$ such that $H=\operatorname{Col}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try read a bit more and look at your answer again after that. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Interestingly, as I learned on this site, there's a result due to Blass, that the ability to choose a basis is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @ChrisCuster That is correct. However, for finitely generated vector spaces like subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ you can construct bases explicitly without involving the axiom of choice at all.

Comment: I see. @Christoph